# Proving an inequality from a given condition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, induction

Consider the following exercise:

> Suppose that $f$ satisfies $$f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\leq\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}.$$ Show that $$f(kx+(1-k)y)\leq kf(x)+(1-k)f(y)$$ whenever $k$ is a rational number between $0$ and $1$, and of the form $\frac{m}{2^n}$

I tried using induction. Suppose the result holds for any $k$ of the form $\frac{m_0}{2^n}$ with $m_0<2^n$. Now suppose that $k=\frac{m}{2^{n+1}}$ with $m<2^{n+1}$. However, I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example for $n=2$ and I hope this will give you some ideas about the induction:
\begin{align*}
f\left(\frac{x}{4}+\frac{3y}{4}\right)=f\left(\frac{x+y}{4}+\frac{y}{2}\right)&\leq\frac{1}{2}f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)+\frac{f(y)}{2} \\
&\leq\frac{f(x)}{4}+\frac{f(y)}{4}+\frac{f(y)}{2} \\
&=\frac{f(x)}{4}+\frac{3f(y)}{4}.
\end{align*}