# showing convexity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convex-analysis

If $f$ satisfies $f([x+y]/2)<[f(x)+f(y)]/2$ show that $ f(kx + (1 − k)y) < kf(x) + (1 − k)f(y) \forall k \in ]0,1[$  such that  $k= \frac{m}{2^n}$, then show that if $f$ is also continous then $f$ is convex.

I know that induction and the equality  $ \frac{m}{2^{n+1}} x+\left(1-\frac{m}{2^{n+1}}\right) y=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{m-2^{n}}{2^{n}} x+\left(1-\frac{m-2^{n}}{2^{n}}\right) y\right]+\frac{x}{2}$ may be usefull.

Comment: It is a duplicate of this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3909140/proving-an-inequality-from-a-given-condition/3909163#3909163. I added a hint there.Besides, from your question, I think you basically know how to tackle on this one.